# Keep active service VPN in background android Java

Tags: java, android, vpn

i have a VPN andrord app Code but when i lock the screen the app disconnects at 3 or 4 minutes after It.
I tried implementing a partial wakeLock and It works but drains much battery and it only works for few hours, i tried disabling optimization mode option but nothing... it only happens when i lock the screen. if i use the app all day it doesn't reconnect and works nice.

This is my start service intent

```
public class TunnelManagerHelper{
    public static void startSocksHttp(Context context) {
        Intent startVPN = new Intent(context, SocksHttpService.class);
        
        if (startVPN != null) {
            TunnelUtils.restartRotateAndRandom();
            
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            //noinspection NewApi
                context.startForegroundService(startVPN);
            else
                context.startService(startVPN);
        }
    }
    
    public static void stopSocksHttp(Context context) {
        Intent stopTunnel = new Intent(SocksHttpService.TUNNEL_SSH_STOP_SERVICE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            .sendBroadcast(stopTunnel);
    }
}
```

My service Code is so extends so i can't post It here.

Comment: It is a strange code. Your service must be foreground, but you need to do it inside your service. why you set your app as foreground?

Answer (score 0):

I try to over-simplify a VPN service for you, but here is required parts for service body:

```
public class MyVpnService extends VpnService {
    private final int MY_VPN_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

    public MyVpnService () {
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        // initializations
        VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
        ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

        try {
            // these parameters should come via parameters
            builder.setMtu(800);
            builder.addAddress("10.1.0.50", 32);
            builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
            builder.addDnsServer(dns);
            builder.setSession("vpn session string");

            mInterface = builder.establish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        // getStatusNotificationBuilder() returns a notification builder for
        // creating your VPN notification which is required for foreground service
        startForeground(MY_VPN_NOTIFICATION_ID, getStatusNotificationBuilder().build());
        return START_STICKY;
   }
}
```

and the body that starts this service in the app:

```
    public void startMyVpn() {
        Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(this);
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, VPN_PREPARE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
            return;
        }

        onActivityResult(VPN_PREPARE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST, RESULT_OK, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == VPN_PREPARE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyVpnService.class);
                mContext.startService(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```